# How to search on Google from gnome-shell overview?

Tags: fedora, gnome3

I'm using Fedora 16 and GNOME 3.2.

When I search in the gnome-shell dash overview and press enter, I am redirected to a "Hello" wiki page. How can I redirect it to a Google search page instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove the Wikipedia search provider:

```
rm /usr/share/gnome-shell/open-search-providers/wikipedia.xml
```

Then, restart gnome-shell:

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `r` and press enter.